# Instalar fancybox 3.0 en wordpress sin plugin

Tags: wordpress

Buenas, estoy intentando instalar el [fancybox 3.0](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) en mi página wordpress, pero no consigo añadir el atributo `data-fancybox=`  para las imágenes o galerías que crea wordpress desde las entradas.

Antes, tenia el plugin **easy fancybox** Pero he decidido quitarlo, por que carga demasiados scripts y la página va más lenta. Con este plugin conseguía que cuando seleccionaba en el enlace de la imagen como **archivo multimedía** me reconocía estos como enlaces de fancybox y me los abria en el pop-up, tambien podía elegir que tipos de archivos quería abrir...

Únicamente he añadido las librerías

**jquery.fancybox.min.css** y **jquery.fancybox.min.js**

Consigo que me los reconozca para las galerías que yo creo manualmente, pues le puedo añadir el atributo `data-fancybox="images"` al botón. 
[Esta es la página en la que funciona bien](https://bewebestudio.es/pagina-web-corporativa/), Las imágenes que abre son los ejemplos de páginas web que hay abajo.

En cambio, [en esta otra](https://bewebestudio.es/publicar-noticia-blog-wordpress/), que es una entrada no consigo que me lo haga automáticamente, ya lo he conseguido con las galerías con el código que dejo después, pero en las imágenes sueltas nada, podría añadir el atributo manualmente, pero en las galerías no encuentro la manera.

En la página de fancybox 3.0 no lo encuentro, he encontrado este script en [surealcms](https://www.surrealcms.com/tuts/how-to-edit-a-fancybox-gallery), y he conseguido que abra las galerías de imágenes.

Ahora necesito que me abra cualquier imagen o pdf que este enlazado desde un botón `<a href="... .jpg">` `<a href="... .pdf">` Esto lo podría hacer manualmente, pero entiendo que lo más cómodo es que lo haga automáticamente.

---

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
    // Don't execute if we're in the Live Editor
    if( !window.isCMS ) {
        // Group images by gallery using `data-fancybox-group` attributes
        var galleryId = 1;
        $('.gallery-group').each( function() {
            $(this).find('a').attr('data-fancybox', 'group');
        });
        
    }
});
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Revisa primero la [documentación](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) y si tienes algún problema en tu implementación, edita tu pregunta siguiendo la guía [mcve]. La pregunta ahora mismo es demasiado amplia para el formato del sitio.

Comment: Buenas toledano, no se como hacer un ejemplo mínimo y verificable, tengo el problema con las galerías que crea wordpress por defecto. Si coloco el código manualmente consigo poner el atributo `data-fancybox="images"` en el botón que enlaza a la imagen y no tengo el problema.  Serviría de algo? gracias

Comment: Consulta la documentación primero e intenta alguna solución que encuentres en Google. Si tienes algún problema sigue la guía que te comento.